# Elastic Map Reduce External Jars

Tags: jar, hadoop, amazon-emr

So, it is easy enough to handle external jars when using hadoop straight up. You have -libjars option that will do this for you. The question is how do you do this with EMR. There must be an easy way of doing it. I thought -cachefile option of the CLI would do it, but I couldn't get it working somehow. Any ideas anyone?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you show the command that was used?

Comment: External Jars and other approaches have been discussed here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24934389/how-to-use-libjars-on-aws-emr

Answer (score 7):

The best luck I have had with external jar dependencies is to copy them (via bootstrap action) to `/home/hadoop/lib` throughout the cluster.  That path is on the classpath of every host.  This technique is the only one that seems to work regardless of where the code lives that accesses external jars (tool, job, or task).

Comment: unable to copy to /home/hadoop/lib

Comment: This Bootstrap approach is good, and as an alternative, which avoids copying the Jar to all nodes (`-libjars` you only need it on the master node after all), you can use the script-runner approach ajduff574 mentioned and I describe in detail in this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27574593/318870

Answer (score 3):

One option is to have the first step in your jobflow set up the JARs wherever they need to be. Or, if they are dependencies, you can package them in with your application JAR (which is probably in S3).

Comment: So, either a bootstrapping script, or something like jarjar to package the jars together is what you are saying? It is too bad that there isn't an easier option.

Comment: There's no other way that I've noticed, at least. It is kind of a shame, but it shouldn't be too difficult to work around.

Comment: You can take a look at Amazon's script-runner jar. You can use it to add your setup as the first step in the jobflow. It will allow you to easily run a script from S3.

Comment: FYI: I've described how to to the script-runner approach in this related SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27574593/318870

Answer (score 0):

FYI for newer versions of EMR /home/hadoop/lib is not used anymore. /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce should be used.