# How to use external jar in EMR?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-emr

My EMR job depends on some external jars which should be present in the classpath while job execution. So I have uploade those jars to a S3 bucket and 
with reference to [How to use -libjars on aws emr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24934389/how-to-use-libjars-on-aws-emr/27574593#27574593) I have tried the copyToLocal operation in haddop. But the bootstrap action complains that /usr/bin/hadoop is not present. It is even failing when use /home/hadoop/bin/hadoop. I want to know how others are downloading jar to each host in BA.

Bash script

```sh
sudo /usr/bin/hadoop fs -copyToLocal 'se://my-bucket/emr-input/dependency-jars/*' /usr/lib/hadoop
```

Error while BA

```sh
sudo: /usr/bin/hadoop: command not found
```

Comment: The post you reference is old so there is likely version differences in EMR releases that are making the implantation difficult. What EMR release version are you using? If 4.x the bootstrap can use AWS CLI to copy on jars (Hadoop is not available until after bootstraps complete).

Answer (score 0):

I followed the second option from this link, and it worked for me

https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/

It worked for cloudera as well ans Amazon's AWS.

Create a *lib* folder in your project folder and add all the external jar files in that *lib* folder. Now create a jar file of your project.

Now when you will run your jar file on cluster ,external dependencies will be handled.